# Converting HTTP Response (Java "Properties" stream format) in to NSDictionary

Tags: java, iphone, httpwebrequest, nsdictionary

I am working on iphone application which contains HTTP Request and  Response.

The format of the response is a key/value format compatible with the Java "Properties" stream format.

I want to store the response into a NSDictionay. Could you suggest me any way to do this?

Thank you.

sangee

### Edit:

Thanks guyz for the quick replies!!!

is their any other ways to store them in NSSdictionay?

I just want to store the album name and description in an array like this:

```
mutablearray = [wrwr, dsf, my album];
```

could you please let me know if this possible or not?

Thanks again!!!

This is the response i got it for my HTTP request...

```
GR2PROTO
debug_album= debug_gallery_version= debug_user=admin debug_user_type=Gallery_User debug_user_already_logged_in= server_version=2.12 status=0 status_text=Login successful.

#GR2PROTO debug_album= debug_gallery_version= debug_user=admin debug_user_type=Gallery_User debug_user_already_logged_in=1

album.name.1=wrwr album.title.1=wrwr album.summary.1= album.parent.1=0 album.resize_size.1=640 album.thumb_size.1=100 album.perms.add.1=true album.perms.write.1=true album.perms.del_item.1=true album.perms.del_alb.1=true album.perms.create_sub.1=true album.info.extrafields.1=Description

album.name.2=dsf album.title.2=dsf album.summary.2= album.parent.2=0 album.resize_size.2=640 album.thumb_size.2=100 album.perms.add.2=true album.perms.write.2=true album.perms.del_item.2=true album.perms.del_alb.2=true album.perms.create_sub.2=true album.info.extrafields.2=Description

album.name.3=my album album.title.3=my album album.summary.3= album.parent.3=0 album.resize_size.3=640 album.thumb_size.3=100 album.perms.add.3=true album.perms.write.3=true album.perms.del_item.3=true album.perms.del_alb.3=true album.perms.create_sub.3=true album.info.extrafields.3=Description
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can, I would recommend serializing the data as JSON (or XML, if you have to) and parsing it using [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON) or a similar parser.  If you really can't, then you'll have to implement your own parser--take a look at [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

Look at NSStream and the [Stream Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html).

Back in the day when Java was fully integrated into Cocoa, NSStream mapped onto Java streams. It still might. IIRC, (it's been a while) NSStream will return a properly populated NSDictionary from a Java stream.

Edit:

It looks like the text returned is just a space delimited hash which is the Java version of dictionary. It takes the form of key=value *space* key=value. The only tricky part is that some of the hashes are nested.

The first line for example is nested:

```
debug_album{ 
    debug_gallery_version{
        debug_user=admin 
        debug_user_type=Gallery_User 
        debug_user_already_logged_in{
            server_version=2.12
            status=0 
            status_text=Login successful.
        }
    }
}
```

You need a recursive scanner to parse that. The "key=space" pattern indicates a nested dictionary.

Comment: You should hit the checkmark next to the answer that resolved your question.